# cgit + uwsgi + nginx not generating the pages for repositories

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, cgit

I am trying to configure cgit with nginx through uwsgi. I managed to get the main page working on example.com/ and added my repos but when I try to access a repo in example.com/somerepo I get a 502 error.

I know cgit is working fine because I can run `cgit.cgi` with and without the `QUERY_STRING="url=somerepo"`environmental variable and it generates the correct html for the main page and the `somerepo` page respectively.

I have been trying to debug the issue using the nginx error logs with debug level, strace and gdb on both nginx and cgit.cgi and the output from uwsgi, this is what I've found so far:

- When I click on a `somerepo` link on cgit's main page uwsgi makes a GET request to `/somerepo` and nginx tries to open a directory in `/htdocs/somerepo` which it can't find because it doesn't exist. (I suppose cgit.cgi should generate this on the fly). I know this from strace `stat("/usr/share/webapps/cgit/1.2.1/htdocs/olisrepo/", 0x7ffdf4c817c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`
- When I click on a `somerepo` link I get `read(8, 0x561749c8afa0, 65536)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)` from cgit.cgi's strace.
- When I try to visit a invalid url like `somerepotypo` it correctly generates a 404 page saying 'no repositories found'.

These are my configuration files:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user nginx nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log debug;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main
        '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
        '"$gzip_ratio"';

    client_header_timeout 10m;
    client_body_timeout 10m;
    send_timeout 10m;

    connection_pool_size 256;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 2k;
    request_pool_size 4k;

    gzip off;

    output_buffers 1 32k;
    postpone_output 1460;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout 75 20;

    ignore_invalid_headers on;

    # Cgit
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        root /usr/share/webapps/cgit/1.2.1/htdocs;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log debug;

        location ~* ^.+(cgit.(css|png)|favicon.ico|robots.txt) {
            root /usr/share/webapps/cgit/1.2.1/htdocs;
            expires 30d;
        }
        location / {
            try_files $uri @cgit;
        }
        location @cgit {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_modifier1 9;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/cgit.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

cgit.ini (I load this using uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi.d/cgit.ini)

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
plugins = cgi
chmod-socket = 666
socket = /run/uwsgi/%n.sock
uid = nginx
gid = nginx
processes = 1
threads = 1
cgi = /usr/share/webapps/cgit/1.2.1/hostroot/cgi-bin/cgit.cgi
```

/etc/cgitrc

```
css=/cgit.css
logo=/cgit.png
mimetype-file=/etc/mime.types
virtual-root=/
remove-suffix=1
enable-git-config=1
scan-path=/usr/local/cgitrepos
```

Can you help me fix this? Thanks in advance